# Laravel8 tdd: session is missing expected key errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-testing

I just want to test an easy input field but I get this error!

[image]

```
/** @test */
public function email_must_be_a_valid_email()
 {
   $response = $this->post('/api/contacts', array_merge($this->data(), ['email' => 'NOT AN EMAIL']));
   $response->assertSessionHasErrors('email');
 }


private function data()
{
  return [
          'name' => 'Test Name',
          'email' => 'test@hotmail.com',
          'birthday' => '05/14/1988',
          'company' => 'ABC String'
        ];
}
```

Thses are the Controller and the request rule.
I hope u can help me with it.

```
class StoreController extends Controller
{
    public function store(ContactsRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validated();
        Contact::create($data);
    }
}

public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'birthday' => 'required',
            'company' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

I hope u can help me with it.

Comment: Sometimes when you have error in your code you get this error in console `Session is missing` while running `composer`, `artisan` or `test` commands

Comment: how can I solve that?

Comment: try some composer or artisan commands if they work or not?

Comment: I have run this, but it does not help----- php artisan config:cache & php artisan config:clear & php artisan view:clear & php artisan cache:clear & composer dump-autoload

Comment: try by adding `Session::start() ` at the beginning of your test

Comment: Also double check if the code is good and bug free, do add the controller code too

Comment: @sohailamar I have used Session::start too but it does not work

Comment: show your controller code, there is some issue in your code that is creating this issue.

Comment: I have just added

Comment: Try `$response->assertSessionHasErrors(['email']);` - [the docs seem to indicate an array is expected](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-session-has-errors).

Comment: No it does not work too:-(

Comment: note: using `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` in the test function might give you more details on the actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your tips. I've solved the problem! But this kind of error message does not help at all to find the solution quickly.
The solution is that I need to be logged in to create contact and then validate form data. But the error message says something completely different!

```
protected $user;

protected function setUp(): void
{
   parent::setUp();
   $this->user = User::factory()->create();
   $this->user->createToken(Str::random(30))->plainTextToken;
}


/** @test */
public function email_must_be_a_valid_email()
{
   $this->actingAs($this->user);
   $response = $this->post('/api/contacts', array_merge($this->data(), ['email' => 'NOT AN EMAIL']));
   $response->assertSessionHasErrors('email');
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an api route then you should use

```
$response->assertJsonValidationErrors(['email']);
```

or

```
$response->assertInvalid(['email']);
```

which works for both JSON and session errors.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-invalid